# What is the best way to plot 3d data in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

If i have data in NxN grid format (for example see [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBbzw.png)) and each cell size is given by (Xmax/N) x (Ymax/N) and data given in each cell is the frequency data of that cell. What is the best way to graphically represent this data in MATLAB such that it is easy to view the frequency for each cell? If I would like to make it like in this example (see [colormap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgeq7.png)), how can I do that what function should I used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice. Here I put several possibilities:

- [bar3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqyWw.png): if you the points are discrete by meaning

[image]

- [surf](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35305-matlab-plot-gallery-surface-plot--1-) or [mesh](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35308-matlab-plot-gallery-mesh-plot) : if the points are continuous by meaning
  [image: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/35305/versions/3/screenshot.jpg]
  [image]

-[imshow](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) or [image](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35301-matlab-plot-gallery-display-image--3-)
[image]

- in MATLAB 2017b or newer, [heatmap](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63457-matlab-plot-gallery-heatmap-chart)
  [image]

-[contour](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35282-matlab-plot-gallery-contour-plot), if you have a sufficiently detailed data

[image]

---

There may be more, please feel free to add them to the post.

Comment: Thank you Ander. I edit my question by adding example of plot that maybe suitable, but I'm not sure what is the Matlab function can be used to generate the plot...any advise?

Comment: The example you posted uses either imshow/image, or surf, and then they  used `view(2)`. But please, do not use the `jet` colormap as in your example ;)